# Splitting a table to varying number of rows with unknown grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with information about service involvement and group assignments for two individuals. A person is identified by `UNIQ_ID`; service start and end dates by `START_DT` and `END_DT`; and their group assignment by `GRP`, which is assigned on `ASSIGN_DT`.

```
UNIQ_ID   START_DT   END_DT   ASSIGN_DT   GRP
888       1-Mar      10-Mar   3-Mar       Red
888       1-Mar      10-Mar   7-Mar       Yellow
999       15-Mar     20-Mar   15-Mar      Yellow
```

A person does not always get their group assignment on their first day - 888 does not, while 999 does. Until a person gets their group assignment, their GRP should be 'Unknown'. Assignment starts on the day of assignment, rather than the following day, and ends the day before the next group assignment, or when their service ends.

Can anyone help me with an efficient way to get to the following result set?

```
UNIQ_ID   ASSIGN_START_DT   ASSIGN_END_DT     GRP
888       1-Mar             2-Mar             Unknown
888       3-Mar             6-Mar             Red
888       7-Mar             10-Mar            Yellow
999       15-Mar            20-Mar            Yellow
```

Reproducible code below:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE_1
(
   UNIQ_ID     NUMBER,
   START_DT    DATE,
   END_DT      DATE,
   ASSIGN_DT   DATE,
   GRP         VARCHAR2 (10)
);
alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mon-yy';
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_1 VALUES (888, TO_DATE('01-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('10-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('03-MAR-20'), 'Red');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_1 VALUES (888, TO_DATE('01-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('10-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('07-MAR-20'), 'Yellow');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_1 VALUES (999, TO_DATE('15-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('20-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('15-MAR-20'), 'Yellow');
```

This is my current solution. Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

```
WITH SEQ1
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT "UNIQ_ID", "DT", "END_DT"
           FROM EXAMPLE_1
                UNPIVOT
                   ("DT" FOR "TIMES" IN ("START_DT", "ASSIGN_DT"))),
     SEQ2
     AS (SELECT t1."UNIQ_ID",
                "DT",
                NVL (
                   LEAD ("DT" - 1, 1)
                      OVER (PARTITION BY "UNIQ_ID" ORDER BY "DT"),
                   "END_DT")
                   AS "END_DT"
           FROM SEQ1 t1),
     SEQ3
     AS (SELECT t1.*, NVL (t2."GRP", 'Unknown') AS "GRP"
           FROM SEQ2 t1
                LEFT JOIN EXAMPLE_1 t2
                   ON     t1."UNIQ_ID" = t2."UNIQ_ID"
                      AND t2."ASSIGN_DT" BETWEEN t1."DT" AND t1."END_DT")
  SELECT *
    FROM SEQ3
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Why do you need "Unknown" assignment and why it starts when first service is started? What if another assignment will be few days after last assignment? Should it be "unknown" too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to combine the state changes into a single table and then use window functions.  This is a little complicated because of overlapping timeframes.  But for the data you provided, this works:

```
with ug as (
       select uniq_id, grp, assign_dt, end_dt
       from example_1
       union all
       select uniq_id, null, start_dt, assign_dt
       from example_1
       where assign_dt <> start_dt
      )
select uniq_id, grp, assign_dt,
       lead(assign_dt, 1, min(end_dt) - 1) over (partition by uniq_id order by assign_dt) as end_dt
from ug
group by uniq_id, grp, assign_dt
order by uniq_id, assign_dt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c9156f3092ef7163f744ee12844ede5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=451aa7885ea0cff1f8b30726ff03a0f1

Comment: I don't think 111 should be Yellow in "05-JUN-20 ~ 15-JUN-20"

Comment: As always, thanks for your help Gordon. This outputted mostly what I needed, except I did have to add a -1 after 'assign_dt' in the lead function to get the exact result set with no overlapping days. thanks for the help!

Comment: @DJC . . . If the other answer produces and incorrect result and this produces a correct result (with the requested modification), why did you accept the other answer?

Comment: Honest mistake on my end. For the actual use case identified, your answer does in-fact win out as it produces the desired result set, where the other answer works better for the business problem at hand (with the incorrect result fixed). My apologies. The answer that I accept should be applicable to the specific question asked.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see there is no need in "Unknown" group, so you can easily get all real assignments with lead():

```sql
WITH SEQ1
     AS (SELECT
            "UNIQ_ID",
            assign_dt,
            least(end_dt, lead(assign_dt-1,1,end_dt)over(partition by uniq_id order by assign_dt)) as end_dt,
            grp
           FROM EXAMPLE_1)
  SELECT *
    FROM SEQ1
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

And your original query doesn't work as you described, please try this sample data:

```sql
begin
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_1 VALUES (888, TO_DATE('01-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('10-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('03-MAR-20'), 'Red');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_1 VALUES (888, TO_DATE('01-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('10-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('07-MAR-20'), 'Yellow');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_1 VALUES (999, TO_DATE('15-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('20-MAR-20'), TO_DATE('15-MAR-20'), 'Yellow');
-- extra:
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_1 VALUES (111, TO_DATE('01-JUN-20'), TO_DATE('10-JUN-20'), TO_DATE('05-JUN-20'), 'Yellow');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_1 VALUES (111, TO_DATE('15-JUN-20'), TO_DATE('20-JUN-20'), TO_DATE('17-JUN-20'), 'Red');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_1 VALUES (111, TO_DATE('15-JUN-20'), TO_DATE('20-JUN-20'), TO_DATE('19-JUN-20'), 'Green');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_1 VALUES (111, TO_DATE('26-JUN-20'), TO_DATE('30-JUN-20'), TO_DATE('27-JUN-20'), 'Yellow');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_1 VALUES (111, TO_DATE('25-JUN-20'), TO_DATE('29-JUN-20'), TO_DATE('28-JUN-20'), 'Black');
commit;
end;
/
```

And describe what exactly do you want to see for 111

Comment: Hey Sayan, thanks for the response - not sure why the sample data didn't work. For the actual business use case, the unknown category isn't technically needed as you said. These results will be split into classification per day and left joined to larger table that has one day per person, including those without classifications, at which point I can simply use NVL to fill in the days with an unknown status. However, if I didn't have that complete table with one day per person to join to, I could see a case in which someone might want to know average delay to group assignment etc. Thanks much!

Comment: Noticed that this result outputted an incorrect row for 111, end date = 6/30. Distinct services can be identified by end dates (which in reality have timestamps on them so okay to distinguish using this method, i.e. no issues with aggregating data mistakenly from same day). believe solution is to add end date in the partition by statement.

also - do you need to take the min of end date and the lead output? i'm getting the same result set without it

Comment: @djc please analyze all the sample data and show what exactly do you want to get. Another answer that you marked as correct one returns yellow for 5 - 15 of june, but the service's end date is 10th of june